# GC_FOR_ALLOC because of call static methods?

Tags: java, android, garbage-collection

I have hundreds of

```
12-26 10:28:42.383: D/dalvikvm(3341): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1122K, 18% free 5834K/7112K, paused 57ms, total 57ms
```

Because of static method(which is calling some times recursively) which I call hundreds times. In this method I have `ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>`
How I can reduce usage of memory?

method called:

```
public static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getTimetableGroupsByType( String typeId ) throws IOException
{
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> timetableItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://plan.polsl.pl/left_menu.php?type=" + typeId).get();
    Elements lists = doc.getElementsByTag("ul");
    for(Element list : lists){

        for( Element item : list.getElementsByTag("li")){
            HashMap<String, String> timetableItem = new HashMap<String, String>();

            timetableItem.put("name", item.text());
            timetableItem.put("id_type", typeId);


            if( ! item.id().equals(""))
            {
                //Log.d("ATS4Handler", item.id() );
                timetableItem.put("id", item.id());
                timetableItem.put("expansible_group", "true");
                timetableItems.add(timetableItem);
                timetableItems.addAll( getTimeTableItemsByGroups( typeId, item.id() ) );
            }
            else{
                String[] itemHref =  item.getElementsByTag("a").first().attr("href").split("=");
                Matcher m = Pattern.compile("([a-zA-Z]+)=([0-9]+)").matcher( item.getElementsByTag("a").first().attr("href") );
                HashMap<String, String> link = new HashMap<String, String>();
                while (m.find())
                    link.put(m.group().split("=")[0], m.group().split("=")[1]);

                timetableItem.put("typeId", typeId);
                timetableItem.put("id", link.get("id").toString() );
                timetableItem.put("expansible_group", "false");
                timetableItems.add(timetableItem);
            }

        }           
    }
    return timetableItems;
}
```

Comment: Forgive me, but there are many problems with this code.  1.  You create the HashMaps locally instead of in the class and re-use then.  2.  You are compiling a regex (the same regex) every time you call the method.  3.  You are creating a new Document, and not re-using the HTTP connection each time.  4.  You are using regex to parse non-regular data (please don't start that storm again he's been locked up in the asylum for months now) etc.  You really should go back to the drawing board and rethnk the design.  The whole thing is horribly inefficient and a memory eater.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have read your code correctly, you are using `HashMap` instances to represent "records" that represent timetable items.  A HashMap is a (relatively) expensive data structure that uses a (relatively) large amount of space.  Instead, you should write and use a custom class with 5 fields.  That will save (probably) 2/3rds of the spave you are using to represent the items data structure.

Another problem is that your "link" `HashMap` seems to be completely unnecessary.  Instead, you could just save the value associated with the key "id" in a simple String variable.  Doing that could reduce the object allocation rate considerably.

However, the biggest consumer of memory is probably the `Document` object that you are getting from JSoup.  Ideally, you don't want to have to create a `Document` object that represents the entire document you are parsing.  Unfortunately, JSoup doesn't support event based parsing.

Comment: Thank you guys for respond. This all is prototype and I thought that when I call static method it will be destroyed after finish with all variables. I will change HashMap to own class and make Document global. 

Again thanks ;)

Comment: The timetableItems object is returned by the method.  Its lifetime depends on what the caller does with it.

Comment: Do you have anything to suggest instead of Jsoup document then ?

Comment: 1) Nope.  2) That question is off-topic.